# Images in UICollectionView automatically flips when scrolled down?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am working with UICollectionView where I am displaying all the images from photo library of the phone.

When I click on any of the image, the image get flipped and and some information regarding the image is displayed.

When the user again clicks on the same image the image flips again and the original image is shown.

The problem is that whenever I scroll down through the UICollectionView the last selected image flips automatically and the information about the image gets displayed.

How to stop this problem.

Here is some code:

```
- (void) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UICollectionViewCell *cell1 = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if(old_path!=NULL){
        UICollectionViewCell *cell2 = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:old_path];
        [UIView transitionFromView:cell2.selectedBackgroundView toView:cell2.contentView duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear |UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:nil];

    }
if(old_path==indexPath&&flag)
{
  [cell1 setSelected:NO];
  [UIView transitionFromView:cell1.selectedBackgroundView toView:cell1.contentView duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear |UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:nil];
    flag=FALSE;
}
else{
    [UIView transitionFromView:cell1.contentView toView:cell1.selectedBackgroundView duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear |UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:nil];
    flag=TRUE;
}
old_path=indexPath;
}
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    ALAsset *asset = assets[indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Description : %@",[asset description]);
    UIImage *img=[self imageWithImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]] convertToSize:CGSizeMake(150, 150)];
    UIView *contents = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
    contents.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:img];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:contents];

    UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    UIButton *del=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    del.frame= CGRectMake(backgroundView.frame.origin.x+20,     backgroundView.frame.origin.y+20, 100, 40);
    [del setTitle:@"Delete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [del addTarget:self action:@selector(delete) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [backgroundView addSubview:del];
    UIButton *cancel=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    cancel.frame= CGRectMake(backgroundView.frame.origin.x+20, backgroundView.frame.origin.y+80, 100, 45);
    [cancel setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cancel addTarget:self action:@selector(cancel) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [backgroundView addSubview:cancel];

    cell.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView;
    [cell bringSubviewToFront:cell.selectedBackgroundView];
    return cell;
}
```

Here, old_path contains the index of the last selected image.

Comment: some codes are needed.. we don't know what you're doing exactly.

Comment: add code for *cellForItemAtIndexPath:* method so that we come to know about how are you drawing cells.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is probably with the UIView transition methods:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:cell1.selectedBackgroundView toView:cell1.contentView duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear |UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:nil];
```

`UICollectionViewCell`'s `contentView` and `selectedBackgroundView` shouldn't be messed with like this, because the cell manages their layout. This code will remove the content view entirely and replace it with the background view, which is expected to be behind the content view when selected, and removed from the view hierarchy when not selected.

The proper way to accomplish what you're doing (showing / hiding the image in response to a tap) would be perform the transition between the image view itself and another subview on the content view.

---

There could also be something in your resizing code that's flipping the image, but it's hard to say without the code for `imageWithImage:convertToSize:`. It would probably be more efficient to get rid of that method, and do something like this:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
imageView.contentsMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]];
[cell.contentsView addSubview:imageView];
```

---

A couple of other observations:

Collection view cells are *reused*, which means that your implementation `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` could end up adding a whole pile of image views to a cell that has been dequeued several times. A better solution would be to subclass `UICollectionViewCell` and add the custom views in its `init` method.

The code `old_path==indexPath` does not actually test for equality between the two index paths, just if the two variables have the same address in memory. Use `[oldPath isEqual:indexPath]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do custom animations on background views without subclassing and handling explicitly. Because collection view automatically brings the `selectedBackgroundView` to top if `selectedBackgroundView` is not same as `backgroundView`. Adding apple documentation for reference.

```
// The background view is a subview behind all other views.
// If selectedBackgroundView is different than backgroundView, it will be placed above the background view and animated in on selection.
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewCell_class/Reference/Reference.html